# No rollback on transaction with R2DBC

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-r2dbc

I try to make transaction with spring-data-r2dbc, which does not work.
When the two query works it's ok, when the first query fails, the second one is not executed. But when the second query fails, the first one is not rollbacked.

I used spring-data-r2dbc in 1.0.0.RELEASE, r2dbc-postgresql in 0.8.1.RELEASE, r2dbc-pool in 0.8.1.RELEASE

```
@Transactional("reactiveTransactionManager")
fun insertPatchAndData(type: String, patch: JsonPatch, data: MyData, userId: String): Mono<Void> {
    return databaseClient.execute("""
                        insert data_patch(
                            id,
                            serial,
                            member_id,
                            system_id,
                            user_id,
                            type_patch,
                            version,
                            data_patch,
                            created_at,
                            modified_at
                        ) values (
                            :id,
                            nextval('data_patch_serial_seq'),
                            :memberId,
                            :systemId,
                            :userId,
                            :type,
                            :version,
                            :patch,
                            :createdAt,
                            :modifiedAt
                        )
                        """.trimIndent())
            .bind("id", data.id)
            .bind("memberId", data.memberId.toString())
            .bind("systemId", "default")
            .bind("userId", userId)
            .bind("type", type)
            .bind("version", 1)
            .bind("patch", Json.of(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(patch)))
            .bind("createdAt", data.createdAt)
            .bind("modifiedAt", OffsetDateTime.now())
            .fetch()
            .then(databaseClient.execute("""
                        insert into
                            data(id, member_id, json_data)
                        values
                            (:id, :memberId, :data)
                        on conflict (id) do
                        update set
                            json_data = :data
                    """.trimMargin()
                    ).bind("id", data.id)
                    .bind("memberId", data.memberId.toString())
                    .bind("data", Json.of(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data)))
                    .fetch().rowsUpdated()).then()
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
class R2dbcConfiguration(private val r2dbcProperties: R2dbcProperties) {

    private lateinit var pool: ConnectionPool

    @Bean
    fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
        val connectionFactoryOptions = ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
            .from(ConnectionFactoryOptions.parse(r2dbcProperties.url))
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.USER, r2dbcProperties.username)
            .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.PASSWORD, r2dbcProperties.password)
            .build()
        return ConnectionFactories.get(connectionFactoryOptions)
    }

    @Bean
    fun pool(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): ConnectionPool {
        val connectionPoolConfiguration = ConnectionPoolConfiguration.builder(connectionFactory)
            .initialSize(r2dbcProperties.pool.initialSize)
            .maxSize(r2dbcProperties.pool.maxSize)
            .build()
        return ConnectionPool(connectionPoolConfiguration)
    }

    @Bean
    fun reactiveTransactionManager(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): ReactiveTransactionManager {
        return R2dbcTransactionManager(connectionFactory)
    }

    @Bean
    fun client(pool: ConnectionPool): DatabaseClient {
        return DatabaseClient.create(pool)
    }

    @PreDestroy
    fun destroy() {
        pool.let { if (!it.isDisposed) it.dispose() }
    }
}
```

On debug I can see that the used PooledConnection has inTransaction attribute at false

Comment: have you looked into their example https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/#r2dbc.datbaseclient.transactions do you have severalTransactionManagers so you need to explicitly state which one in `@Transactional("reactiveTransactionManager")`

Comment: I have a transaction manager used by Liquibase and JDBC, which is already called transactionManager

Comment: maybe look over how you have implemented your connection manager and consider extending the `AbstractR2dbcConfiguration`